# Threshold exceed check by two tables

Tags: r, dataframe

**1st table** --> Threshold data frame which has **threshold for respective label**

```
threshold <- data.frame(label=c("a","b", "c", "a","d", "e", "f"), threshold = c(12, 10, 20, 12, 12, 35, 40))
```

[image]

*[this table will have repetition at the same time the repeated label will have the same threshold like "a" ]*

**The 2nd table** --- > contains value,label along with unique id

```
data_id <- data.frame(id =c(1,2,1,4),label=c("a","b","a","b"), value =c(32.1,0,15.0,10))
```

[image]

This i should  check with the previous table for value exceeding the respective threshold considering each unique id.

*[For each id how many times it exceeded the threshold for respective label and its threshold]*

And finally i am expecting a table like this
**[To calculate total number of exceeding values for each unique id & label combination]**

[image: Final Table]

I can do this by taking the respective label using if condition but i would like to get a dynamic way in less time.**[I have millions of records]**

Comment: How do you distinguish `2 b` and `4 b` in `data_id ` with that of in `threshold` ?

Comment: 2,4 is unique id while "b" is label from threshold so finally i should get for total number of exceeding values for each unique id & label combination

Answer (score 1):

I didn't understand your goal clearly but looking at your final data frame, I am assuming you want to get the total number of exceeding values for each unique id & label combination. Below is a possible `dplyr` solution:

```
library(dplyr)

final_df <- data_id %>%
  left_join(unique(threshold), by = "label") %>%
  mutate(check = if_else(value > threshold, 1, 0)) %>%
  group_by(id, label) %>%
  summarise(exceed = sum(check))

final_df
# # A tibble: 3 x 3
# # Groups:   id [?]
#      id label exceed
#   <dbl> <chr>  <dbl>
# 1     1 a          2
# 2     2 b          0
# 3     4 b          0
```

Please note that you will get a warning while joining the data frames because labels are initially defined as factors with different levels. You may want to set `stringsAsFactors = F` to create your data frames for consistency.